# Как пофиксить ошибку загрузки аккаунта при конвертации tdata в session?

Tags: python, telethon

Взял готовый код из docks opentele, и столкнулся с неизвестной мне ошибкой

Мой код:

```
from opentele.td import TDesktop
from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
from opentele.api import API, UseCurrentSession
import asyncio

async def main():

    # Load TDesktop client from tdata folder
    tdataFolder = r"F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\tdata"
    tdesk = TDesktop(tdataFolder)

    # Check if we have loaded any accounts
    assert tdesk.isLoaded()

    # flag=UseCurrentSession
    #
    # Convert TDesktop to Telethon using the current session.
    client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session="telethon.session", flag=UseCurrentSession)

    # Connect and print all logged-in sessions of this client.
    # Telethon will save the session to telethon.session on creation.
    await client.connect()
    await client.PrintSessions()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\main.py", line 10, in main
    tdesk = TDesktop(tdataFolder)
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\venv\lib\site-packages\opentele\td\tdesktop.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.LoadTData()
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\venv\lib\site-packages\opentele\td\tdesktop.py", line 194, in LoadTData
    raise e
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\venv\lib\site-packages\opentele\td\tdesktop.py", line 185, in LoadTData
    self.__loadFromTData()
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\venv\lib\site-packages\opentele\td\tdesktop.py", line 363, in __loadFromTData
    Expects(len(self.accounts) > 0, "No account has been loaded")
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\venv\lib\site-packages\opentele\exception.py", line 284, in Expects
    raise exception
  File "F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\venv\lib\site-packages\opentele\td\tdesktop.py", line 363, in __loadFromTData
    Expects(len(self.accounts) > 0, "No account has been loaded")
opentele.exception.OpenTeleException: Unexpected Exception: No account has been loaded [ Called by BaseObject.TDesktop.__loadFromTData() ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже с этим сталкиваюсь, иногда работет но кажется только с tdata из старых версий Telegram Desktop. Я думаю, что к сожалению это может быть связано с устарением opentele...ведь проект практически не обновляется, и наверно были какие то изменения в структуре папки или файлов tdata.